# Extracting MAC Address located between 'link/ether & brd'

Tags: python, regex

> I try to get only the **MAC address** that is between `link/ether` and `brd`.

Here is the code I have so far, is part of a larger file and included a sample:

```
import re
data = '''1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:b5:12:02:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff '''
p = re.compile(r'(?:[0-9a-fA-F]:?){12}')
re.findall(p, line)
```

> Managed to get the following output:

```
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
link/ether 00:15:b8:12:09:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

> Issue: I try to get the following output(from each line that start with the `link/ether` to get the mac address that is between `link/ether & brd`) :

```
00:15:b8:12:09:00
```

Comment: This looks like output from an executable.  Why are you trying to parse the text instead of using the relevant module to pull the mac address from a device?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1, I'm recreating the ".rules" files and need to extract specific parts from output commands ... basically searching in a lot of files parsing the output and rewrite them.

Comment: this mac addresses are getting validated with another script to match the profiles before re-writing.

Comment: Try `p = re.compile(r'^\s*link/ether\s+([0-9a-fA-F]+(?::[0-9a-fA-F]+){5})\s+brd', re.M)`, see https://ideone.com/Xoolx3

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, generated the expected output!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
 p = re.compile(r'^\s*link/ether\s+([0-9a-fA-F]+(?::[0-9a-fA-F]+){5})\s+brd', re.M)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G8HZbl/1) and the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=m&re=%5E%5Cs*link%2Fether%5Cs%2B(%5B0-9a-fA-F%5D%2B(%3F%3A%3A%5B0-9a-fA-F%5D%2B)%7B5%7D)%5Cs%2Bbrd):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `link/ether` - a literal substring
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `([0-9a-fA-F]+(?::[0-9a-fA-F]+){5})` - Capturing group 1 (what `re.findall` returns): 1 or more hex chars followed with 5 occurrences of `:` followed with 1+ hex chars
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `brd` - `brd` substring.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Xoolx3):

```
import re
data = '''1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:b5:12:02:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff '''
p = re.compile(r'^\s*link/ether\s+([0-9a-fA-F]+(?::[0-9a-fA-F]+){5})\s+brd', re.M)
print(p.findall(data)) # => ['00:25:b5:12:02:00']
```

Comment: Why we don’t define the end ? All documentation does use the `brd$` but if we define the end than is not detecting the MAC ...

Comment: @n1tk `$` matches the end of a line. If you need to match `brd` as a whole word, use `\b` instead.